# How to increment row object_id on condition in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

This is example table:

```
id | object_class | object_id | name     |
1  | 1            | 1         | potato   |
2  | 1            | 2         | tomato   |
3  | 2            | 1         | wheel    |
4  | 2            | 2         | seat     |
```

id auto increments. For example I want to add row for object_class when its equal 1. How do I tell mysql that on creating new row, check object_id's in object class, find biggest one and create row with object_id+1? And in case object_class doesnt exist, create new row with object_id starting from 1? So it adds:

```
5 | 1             | 3         | foo     | (for existing)
6 | 3             | 1         | bar     | (for new object_class)
```

I do understand I could somehow (if above is not possible, please explain best optimized way to do this with few queries) fetch object_id's for certain object_class and then find the biggest one. After that create new row with object_id, calculated manually. But it seems like a lot of work to do.

I want to note that I don't know much about mysql tables optimization.

Also, Im using laravel 5 framework.

Edit: 
Just noticed laravel has Aggregate MAX http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries
Is it good approach to get max value and then create new row with max+1?

Comment: Have you looked into writing a stored procedure which you can call which will handle this?  That's the best method I can come up with.  The easier method would be to create an event handler whenever something is saved in this table that would query the table first to set the object_class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four ways you can accomplish this.

1. Do everything in your php code. Add the row, query the database to get the max value. Create new record. All this is done in php, with autocommit set to false. If something goes wrong, you want to be able to rollback. Either everything goes as planned and the two rows get inserted as they should, or nothing is inserted.
2. This is the same as the above. All php, but instead of search the database for the max values, you keep a cache. The steps are like this: insert the row, search the cache for what need, insert the second row, update the cache. This will be even faster, but it's troublesome, because you'll have to think about memory issues. Is it some simple data structure, or some framework that provides this kind of functionality? These are hard to decide from the start.
3. Make a procedure that is run `ON INSERT`. When you insert the row, this trigger will be activated and it will run you SQL code. The procedure will check for the max, and then insert the new row.
4. The same as 2, but run you can run your procedure via php, and not via trigger.

I'm all for case 1 and 2. I tend to avoid procedures and triggers as much as possible. I don't want my business logic to be allover the place. I try to keep everything in my code, since it's more maintainable and easier to debug. Also logging is easier. Someone that is new to the codebase can follow the steps with less effort. Of course that's my approach, it's not necessarily the right way. In some cases a procedure called via code or even via a trigger can be very effective, but I don't see this in your case.

Deciding between 1 and 2, well this is tricky. It depends on your application and what you want to achieve. 1 is straightforward and if it's slow you try to optimize by indexing. If this works, then go with this. Is so much simpler. If it doesn't though, then you have to think about case 2. Keep a cache for the values you need, instead of querying the database. At startup you initialize the cache (this is done once on startup, so even if it's a little slow, it's just once). Then keep your cache up to date. If something simple and custom made is ok, then great go with that. If not though, then you start searching for some framework that handles this kind of stuff.

There's my two cents. I hope this was helpful. Have fun

@zerkms provided some very useful insight. You always have the concurrency problems. So basically I know two ways of tackling this.

1. Full lock table (pessimistic lock) when making the transaction (all three steps). When one transaction takes place, no other can do the same thing, otherwise it will mess the query of the max value you are after. This is not recommended, especially if the application intends to serve some traffic.
2. Keep the values you need in a synchronized structure. Check case 2. This is recommended. This way the bottleneck will only happen for a quick look up and not for a full on database transaction.

Comment: I should add index on my where column with 1st approach to keep everything fast, right?

Comment: You could do that, yes. But keep in mind, implement first, optimize later. Get this thing working and after that check where the bottleneck is. An index would be a straightforward solution. A cache where you keep the latest object_class - object_id pair, would be a good solution too. But an index is much simpler, so keep that as a first approach when and if is needed. Indexes have their drawbacks too.

Comment: The answer does not cover any potential concurrency issues, which is a common thing in such implementation.

Comment: Mea culpa. You are right. I'll try to update. Feel free to provide a better answer though. The OP can always change the answer that he/she chose